# Is there a way I can get the Difference instead of the SUM on this report column

Tags: reporting-services

I'm not sure if this is enough info, but how would I enter the expression here to calculate the difference in income vs expense and then a total of those amounts:?

[image]

What I would like is something like:

```
balance = SUM(amount) when IncomeExpense = "Income" - SUM(amount) when IncomeExpnese = "Expense

balanceTotal = SUM(balance)
```

Every time I try to enter an expression into those fields, I get #Error on my report.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, any advice would be great, I'm obviously very new to "Expression" writing.  If more info is necessary, I can get it.  Thanks I appreciate any help!

Update: This is the Report being viewed, I've circled the values I want to find the difference:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value * Iif(Fields!IncomeExpense.Value = "Income", 1.0, -1.0))
```

or if you don't like to multiply the values

```
=Sum(Iif(Fields!IncomeExpense.Value = "Income", Fields!Amount.Value, -Fields!Amount.Value))
```

The function for total should be the same. I presume you only have Income and Expense as values. If you want to explicitly check for Expense you can replace the Iif with a Switch statement like Switch(Income, +amount, Expense, -amount) in pseudocode.

EDIT: about expression editing: I find the easiest way to enter these expressions is in the expression builder/editor. Right-click on a box and you should be able to select "Expression" with a f(x) like icon.

The [Sum(Amount)] is another way of entering an expression but for calculations like this you will need to edit expressions most of the time. In the background, [Sum(Amount)] is also an expression: `=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)`. Try it out by editing the expression one of your existing totals.

Comment: Thanks @HB, this is very helpful, and using your Expression examples, I'm able to get some numbers to print instead of #Error.  I'm going to play around with the expression to see if i can obtain the values I want, and subtract them.  I've updated my question with a picture of the results, and the numbers I want to subtract, and my expected outcome.  Using your method is it possible to reference those numbers, and subtract them?

Comment: It is not possible to reference certain other subtotal fields in a matrix if that's what you mean. You will need to write an expression that evaluates all rows again and does the calculation for a total "on its own". In the expressions I provided you can see that: Fields!Amount.Value goes back to the source if you see what i mean.

Which rows exactly are aggregated by a Sum is determined by its Scope. In other words: the same function in a different place can have a different outcome. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255256.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It sounds like what I want to do (simply reference subtotal fields, and subtract them) isn't possible.  Thanks for the article on technet for Expressions, I'll have to read up on that, then I might have a better grasp on your examples, and what you mean by "write an expression that evaluates all rows again and does the calculation".  In the mean time I may just write the subtraction into the query, and reference it that way.  Thanks!